# What are the characteristics of an Abelian Sandpiles for a grid 3 x 3?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a C project which involves Abelian Sandpiles. The issue is, after a few days of research, I am still struggling to understand the characteristics of a Sandpile.

Our project instructions are:

> Write a function that computes the sum of two sandpiles

- A sandpile is considered stable when none of its cells contains more than 3 grains
- When your function is done, grid1 must be stable

The function returns void and takes two int parameters int `grid1[3][3]`, `int grid2[3][3]`.

An example of the expected output is:

```
3 3 3   1 3 1
3 3 3 + 3 3 3
3 3 3   1 3 1
=
4 6 4
6 6 6
4 6 4
=
2 5 2
5 6 5
2 5 2
=
4 2 4
2 6 2
4 2 4
=
0 5 0
5 2 5
0 5 0
=
2 1 2
1 6 1
2 1 2
=
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
```

I understand how

```
3 3 3   1 3 1   4 6 4
3 3 3 + 3 3 3 = 6 6 6
3 3 3   1 3 1   4 6 4
```

but then for the next grid, do the sandpiles fall off the board? Which number loses sand first?

I am not asking for help on how to actually code the problem. I think once I have a grasp on Sandpiles I will be able to do that on my own.

I am asking if anybody could explain to me the exact characteristics of a finite (3 x 3) Abelian Sandpile in clear terms.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. You can use any major search engine to look this up. Wikipedia has plenty of detailed info, for example.

Comment: Wikipedia on [Abelian Sandpile model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model) says: _If a vertex at the boundary of the domain topples, this results in a net loss of grains (two grains at the corner of the grid, one grain otherwise)._. Yes, grains fall off the grid.

Comment: Thank you. As I said in my original post I have spent the last day googling and watching the great Numberphile video. The problem was that I wasn't 100% clear on on the rules for each iteration of grid.

Comment: "Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site."

Say what?! People use Stack Overflow to ask specific questions about a topic in order to understand it better? Maybe it's not a tutorial site, but I don't think I treated it as if it were. 

If it's not a tutorial site (which I don't even disagree with you on) than what is it, in your opinion? And what about my question was off base? I didn't understand how the grains topple for each iteration of Sandpile. @JonathanLeffler answered my question.

If you downvoted my question, please consider reversing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by looking at your grids, I think it works like this:

If a cell is stable (... <= 3), it does not lose any grains. If it is unstable (... > 3), then it will lose a grain to every stable neighbour cell. The corner cells will, if unstable, always lose 2 grains (they "fall off the board"). Similarly, the cells on the edge will, if unstable, always lose 1 grain (it "falls off the board").

This algorithm is performed for each cell of the original "input" grid; therefore, the order should not matter.

Comment: I believe that if a cell is unstable, it loses 4 grains unconditionally — and if it is at the edge, one grain 'falls off' and if it is at a corner, two grains 'fall off'.  And it doesn't matter whether the neighbour cell is stable or not; the migration occurs anyway.  That's probably just subtlety of wording rather than anything else, though.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and is probably more correct than the rule I came up with. I think that just by looking at the upper example, the algorithm cannot be unambiguously derived anyway. So it is certainly a good idea to look it up...